# Failed in connecting ipynb-file to kernel in Jupyter Notebook, py-file works

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open an .ipynb-file to the kernel in Jupyter notebook. It opens but it fails to connect, I tried it both via Python and with Anaconda.
When I open a .py-file it works fine for both Anaconda and via Python, it connects to the kernel and I can work with it.

Just the file with R doesn't work. It also happened very suddenly. I was working on a file in Jupyter, then I made a copy of that file, because I wanted to make some changes and this file wasn't connecting to the kernel. Then I tried to write on the first file and this one also wasn't connecting anymore.

I also deleted that copy I made, but still it doesn't work.
I uninstalled both Anaconda and Python and installed the newest versions. No change. Still no connecting to the kernel.

Any idea is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating R solved the issue :) damn I'm so stupid